# Over-release that makes the window go numb

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using Xcode 4.2 to write and Clang 3.0 to build a program that demonstrates a particular crash.

The program has a window that it means to keep around that is set in the nib to “Release When Closed”, so it's over-released in subsequent uses. It's meant to be a sheet, so it's shown using `beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`. Trying to show the window a second or third time should crash the app.

I remember that happening a year ago, with the program receiving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and that triggering the debugger to stop at that point. I also remember being able to hunt the problem down in Instruments using the Zombies template.

That's what I want (this program is part of a presentation to show debugging techniques), but that's not what's happening now. Now, the program doesn't crash; Instruments shows that the retain count on the window gets down to 1 twice, but no lower, so it does not get deallocated.

That would be fine if the problem stopped there; I could simply hide and show the sheet another time or two. The problem is, the second time I bring up the (should-be-dead-but-still-has-at-least-one-retain-keeping-it-alive) sheet, it's numb.

By that I mean that neither the sheet nor any control in it (it contains a field, a text view, and two buttons) responds to events. The heartbeat does nothing in it; the window has an OK button, but when the window is numb, the OK button does not pulse. Nothing works to dismiss the sheet.

But the program is not crashed. I can still interact with the menus and the Dock shows that the program is responding. If I try to quit it, it beeps, since it has a sheet up.

What's causing the window to go numb, and what can I do about it?

Here's a reduced version of the program that also exhibits the problem: https://github.com/boredzo/NumbWindow

Comment: Addendum: Playing with the test app further, it looks like the sheet comes back in whatever state it left in. If I close it by clicking on the Cancel button, then the Cancel button is still highlighted when it comes back.

Comment: @NJones: Nope. I'll probably be sticking to MRC in this program and presentation as long as there's a good chance new Cocoa programmers will need to use MRC code, even if they don't write it yet.

Comment: You definitely should teach MRC. ARC is NOT garbage collection, it is essentially Automated MRC. If you don't understand the fundamentals you wont know what it's doing. (Sorry for being off-topic)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you should be using `-close` to make the sheet go away.  If you change the `[sheet close];` line to be `[sheet orderOut:self];`, then it works properly.

As for *why* they're different, I don't know.  But my experience has been to always use `-orderOut:` to dismiss sheets, and never `-close`.  [The documentation backs me up on this:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html)

> **Listing 3**  Did-end selector

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

tl;dr:

You're using the wrong method to make the panel go away.

Comment: Interesting. The downside is that I'll need to think of some other way to implement the bug with RWC, but that's a problem for another day. Thanks.

Comment: FTD: "Calling the `orderOut:` method causes the window to be removed from the screen, but does not cause it to be released. See the `close` method for information on when a window is released." (I also almost never use `-close`);

Comment: The documentation does recommend `orderOut:`, but doesn't specifically contraindicate `close` or give any reason that I could see why not.